# Constructing an overridable implicit

Tags: scala, implicits

I would like to implement a generic implicit for a class that can be overriden. As following:

**tooling.scala**

```
package tooling    

case class Tool( msg: String)

class Toolkit{
  def usingTool(source:String)(implicit tool:Tool){
    println( s"[$source] using tool: ${tool.msg}" )
  }
}
```

**user.scala**

```
package user

class User{
  val toolkit = new Toolkit()

  def usingGenericTool(){
    toolkit.usingTool( "from generic usage")
  }

  def usingSpecificTool(){
    implicit lazy val tool = Tool("shovel")
    toolkit.usingTool( "from generic usage")
  }
}
```

If I define a generic implicit `Tool` implementation in a companion object or trait, I get the warning that *tool* and the generic implicit are `ambiguous implicit values`.

How can I define a generic implicit val that still can be overridden in the scope of a method and reused in various classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `implicit` parameters as if they were ordinary ones, i.e.:

```
toolkit.usingTool("from generic usage")(Tool("shovel"))
```

Also each implicit member is a priority — implicit that are defined in ancestor classes overrides implicits defined in parent classes, even with different name.

So the following example will print `2`:

```
trait LowPriorityImplicit {
  implicit val x = 1
}

object Test extends LowPriorityImplicit {
  implicit val y = 2

  def f(implicit i: Int) = println(i)

  f // => 2
}
```

Comment: I don't want to, since I'll be calling that method several times

Comment: As far as I know, there is no priority mechanism for implicits defined in same class. For implicits in class hierarchy — I updated my answer.

Comment: But if I define the implicit in the Test trait, as you showed in your example, I CAN'T define an implicit in the method body of the Test class.

Comment: That's what I said in a comment above.

Comment: But they aren't defined in the same class... One in the trait and the other in a method of a class extending that trot. Also, in your example you are overriding the trait implicit in the object implicit. So why not in its method?

Answer (score 1):

Define the default implicit in the companion object of `Tool`:

```
case class Tool( msg: String)
object Tool {
  implicit val defaultTool: Tool = Tool("Generic")
}
```

And you can override it by importing other tools, or creating an implicit `Tool` variable:

```
object Tools {
  implicit val Special: Tool = Tool("special")
}

def usingTools(): Unit = {
  val toolkit = new Toolkit()
  toolkit.usingTool("using the default")

  { // importing an override
    import Tools.Special
    toolkit.usingTool("using imported")
  }

  { // creating an override
    implicit val anotherTool: Tool = Tool("local")
    toolkit.usingTool("using local implicit val")

    // using a Tool other then the currently imported as an exception:
    toolkit.usingTool("overriding once manually")(Tool("manual"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code of `Tool` you can define default implicit in the companion object of `Tool` (not companion of `Toolkit` or `User`). Local implicit "overrides" implicit in companion.

```
case class Tool(msg: String)
object Tool {
  implicit lazy val tool = Tool("default")
}

u.usingGenericTool() //[from generic usage] using tool: default
u.usingSpecificTool() // [from generic usage] using tool: shovel
```

Suppose you don't have access to the code of `Tool`. Indeed, if you define the default implicit locally or in a parent of `User` you'll have error `ambiguous implicit values`. You can hide implicit by name

```
class User {
  val toolkit = new Toolkit()
  implicit lazy val tool = Tool("default")

  def usingGenericTool() {
    toolkit.usingTool("from generic usage")
  }

  def usingSpecificTool() {
    implicit lazy val tool = Tool("shovel") // the same name!
    toolkit.usingTool("from generic usage")
  }
}

val u = new user.User
u.usingGenericTool() //[from generic usage] using tool: default
u.usingSpecificTool() // [from generic usage] using tool: shovel
```

[NullPointerException on implicit resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917884/nullpointerexception-on-implicit-resolution)

[Caching the circe implicitly resolved Encoder/Decoder instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411094/caching-the-circe-implicitly-resolved-encoder-decoder-instances)

[How can an implicit be unimported from the Scala repl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592324/how-can-an-implicit-be-unimported-from-the-scala-repl)

[Scala implicit def do not work if the def name is toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872032/scala-implicit-def-do-not-work-if-the-def-name-is-tostring)

[Is there a workaround for this format parameter in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712378/is-there-a-workaround-for-this-format-parameter-in-scala)

Another option is `shapeless.LowPriority` (names of implicits can be different)

```
// libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10"
class User {
  val toolkit = new Toolkit()
  implicit def tool0(implicit lp: LowPriority) = Tool("default")

  def usingGenericTool() {
    toolkit.usingTool("from generic usage")
  }

  def usingSpecificTool() {
    implicit lazy val tool = Tool("shovel")
    toolkit.usingTool("from generic usage")
  }
}

u.usingGenericTool() //[from generic usage] using tool: default
u.usingSpecificTool() // [from generic usage] using tool: shovel
```

[Implicit parameter precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68046952/implicit-parameter-precedence)

[General way of ensuring implicit definition always has higher/lower priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232605/general-way-of-ensuring-implicit-definition-always-has-higher-lower-priority)

If you have access to the code of `Toolkit` you can use default parameter

```
class Toolkit {
  def usingTool(source: String)(implicit tool: Tool = Tool("default")) {
    println(s"[$source] using tool: ${tool.msg}")
  }
}

u.usingGenericTool() //[from generic usage] using tool: default
u.usingSpecificTool() // [from generic usage] using tool: shovel
```

In Scala 3 there is `scala.compiletime.summonFrom`

```
def usingGenericTool() = {
  inline given Tool = summonFrom {
    case given Tool => summon[Tool]
    case _ => Tool("default")
  }
  toolkit.usingTool("from generic usage")
}

u.usingGenericTool() //[from generic usage] using tool: default
u.usingSpecificTool() // [from generic usage] using tool: shovel
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html#summoning-implicits-selectively

In Scala 2 we can achieve this behavior with a macro

```
def usingGenericTool(): Unit = {
  implicit lazy val tool0: Tool = summonOrElse(Tool("default"))
  toolkit.usingTool("from generic usage")
}

u.usingGenericTool() //[from generic usage] using tool: default
u.usingSpecificTool() // [from generic usage] using tool: shovel

// in a different subproject
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def summonOrElse[A](default: A): A = macro summonOrElseImpl[A]

def summonOrElseImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(default: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  c.typecheck(q"""
    val ${c.internal.enclosingOwner.name.toTermName} = null
    _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[${weakTypeOf[A]}]
  """, silent = true) match {
    case EmptyTree => default
    case t => t
  }
}
```

See also

[Finding the second matching implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56777174/finding-the-second-matching-implicit)

[create an ambiguous low priority implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462253/create-an-ambiguous-low-priority-implicit)