# NullPointerException on implicit resolution

Tags: scala, implicit

This code results in NullPointerException:

```scala
import anotherpackage.MyContext
import anotherpackage.builders.aMyContext

case class Context(id: String)
object Context {
  implicit def `ContextHolder to Context`(implicit holder: ContextHolder): Context = holder.context
}
trait ContextHolder {
  def context: Context
}

object anotherpackage {
  case class MyContext(name: String, context: Context) extends ContextHolder

  object builders {
    def aMyContext(name: String)(implicit context: Context = Context("test")): MyContext =
      MyContext(name, context)
  }
}

object SimpleDemo extends App {
  implicit val myContext: MyContext = aMyContext("name")
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Context$.ContextHolder$u0020to$u0020Context(SimpleDemo.scala:8)
    at SimpleDemo$.delayedEndpoint$SimpleDemo$1(SimpleDemo.scala:24)
    at SimpleDemo$delayedInit$body.apply(SimpleDemo.scala:23)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at SimpleDemo$.main(SimpleDemo.scala:23)
    at SimpleDemo.main(SimpleDemo.scala)
```

Why does Scala resolves implicit parameter for function `aMyContext` to itself:

```scala
implicit val myContext: MyContext = aMyContext("name")
```

Yes, aMyContext gets implicit Context and for MyContext there's an implicit conversion to Context. But how can it resolve it to the field itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
implicit val myContext: MyContext = {
  val myContext = null
  aMyContext("name")
}
```

hiding the name of implicit.

[Caching the circe implicitly resolved Encoder/Decoder instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411094/caching-the-circe-implicitly-resolved-encoder-decoder-instances)

[How can an implicit be unimported from the Scala repl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592324/how-can-an-implicit-be-unimported-from-the-scala-repl)

[Scala implicit def do not work if the def name is toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872032/scala-implicit-def-do-not-work-if-the-def-name-is-tostring)

[video] [Some Mistakes We Made When Designing Implicits](https://youtu.be/1h8xNBykZqM?t=678) (11:18)

Comment: This trick does work, thanks. It's just a bit frustrating that scala works this way.

Comment: @DmitryKomanov I guess this is intentional. Think of recursive implicits like `implicit def succDouble[N <: Nat](implicit double: Double[N]): Double.Aux[Succ[N], Succ[Succ[double.Out]]] = null`. Maybe by default `myContext` must be in scope when is being defined.