# Scala Implicit Method Compilation when Method Tries to Access Non-Existing Case Class Members

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-compiler

I did run into an scala compiler issue with implicit methods. The scenario is quite easy. The task of the implicit method is to turn an object of the case class A into an object of the case class B. The implicit method implementation accesses a case class member of A which does not exist. If the case class member does not exist at all in case class A or B (e.g. foobar), the compiler throws an error. If the case class member does exist in case class B, the compiler does not throw an error, even if I access case class A with this name (i.e. member x).

I am using Scala in version 2.13.1. Currently, 2.13.2 is the most current version.

The following code shows the scenario in more detail. The following code will lead to a compiler error.

```
package Hokuspokus

object ImplicitMagic extends App {

  case class A(a: String, b: String, c: String)
  case class B(d: String, e: String, f: String, x: String)

  implicit def AtoB: A => B = a => B(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.foobar)

  def print(b: B): Unit = {
    System.out.println("Print" + b.d)
  }

  val a = A("foo", "bar", "asdf")

  print(a)

}
```

The compiler states following error:

```
[ERROR]   implicit def AtoB: A => B = a => B(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.foobar)
[ERROR]                                                       ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

However, the following code is not running into a compiler error, even if x is not a member of a case class:

```
package Hokuspokus

object ImplicitMagic extends App {

  case class A(a: String, b: String, c: String)
  case class B(d: String, e: String, f: String, x: String)

  implicit def AtoB: A => B = a => B(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.x)

  def print(b: B): Unit = {
    System.out.println("Print" + b.d)
  }

  val a = A("foo", "bar", "asdf")

  print(a)

}
```

I am wondering now, why the scala compiler is not detecting this issue during compile time. In order to understand what the scalac compiler does, I investigated the compiled scala classes, but so far I did not come up with a conclusion.

```
package Hokuspokus
object ImplicitMagic extends scala.AnyRef with scala.App {
  def this() = { /* compiled code */ }
  case class A(a: scala.Predef.String, b: scala.Predef.String, c: scala.Predef.String) extends scala.AnyRef with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
    val a: scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    val b: scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    val c: scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    def copy(a: scala.Predef.String, b: scala.Predef.String, c: scala.Predef.String): Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.A = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def productPrefix: java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    def productArity: scala.Int = { /* compiled code */ }
    def productElement(x$1: scala.Int): scala.Any = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def productIterator: scala.collection.Iterator[scala.Any] = { /* compiled code */ }
    def canEqual(x$1: scala.Any): scala.Boolean = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def productElementName(x$1: scala.Int): java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def hashCode(): scala.Int = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def toString(): java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def equals(x$1: scala.Any): scala.Boolean = { /* compiled code */ }
  }
  object A extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction3[scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String, Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.A] with java.io.Serializable {
    def this() = { /* compiled code */ }
    final override def toString(): java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    def apply(a: scala.Predef.String, b: scala.Predef.String, c: scala.Predef.String): Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.A = { /* compiled code */ }
    def unapply(x$0: Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.A): scala.Option[scala.Tuple3[scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String]] = { /* compiled code */ }
  }
  case class B(d: scala.Predef.String, e: scala.Predef.String, f: scala.Predef.String, x: scala.Predef.String) extends scala.AnyRef with scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
    val d: scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    val e: scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    val f: scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    val x: scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    def copy(d: scala.Predef.String, e: scala.Predef.String, f: scala.Predef.String, x: scala.Predef.String): Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.B = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def productPrefix: java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    def productArity: scala.Int = { /* compiled code */ }
    def productElement(x$1: scala.Int): scala.Any = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def productIterator: scala.collection.Iterator[scala.Any] = { /* compiled code */ }
    def canEqual(x$1: scala.Any): scala.Boolean = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def productElementName(x$1: scala.Int): java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def hashCode(): scala.Int = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def toString(): java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    override def equals(x$1: scala.Any): scala.Boolean = { /* compiled code */ }
  }
  object B extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction4[scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String, Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.B] with java.io.Serializable {
    def this() = { /* compiled code */ }
    final override def toString(): java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
    def apply(d: scala.Predef.String, e: scala.Predef.String, f: scala.Predef.String, x: scala.Predef.String): Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.B = { /* compiled code */ }
    def unapply(x$0: Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.B): scala.Option[scala.Tuple4[scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String]] = { /* compiled code */ }
  }
  implicit def AtoB: scala.Function1[Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.A, Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.B] = { /* compiled code */ }
  def print(b: Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.B): scala.Unit = { /* compiled code */ }
  val a: Hokuspokus.ImplicitMagic.A = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Comment: Works in dotty. There is also compiler flag `-Wself-implicit` but does not seem to catch it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917884/nullpointerexception-on-implicit-resolution

Comment: @MarioGalic It seems implicit conversion can't be hidden by name either. `implicit val f: Int => String = {
    implicit val f = null;

    implicitly[Int => String];

    _ => ""
  }` still compiles although `implicit val i: Int = {
    implicit val i = null;

    implicitly[Int];

    0
  }` doesn't.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thanks for sharing. In the second case if the implicit value is a simple type it is working as it is not compiling which is good, in the first case if the implicit value is a lambda function it is compiling which is not good. I think this is also at least dangerous as lambdas should be treated as first class citizens of the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler is doing multiple things to resolve a missing method/val `a.foobar`.

It will check if this method belongs to `case class A`, it will check if A can be implicitly converted to a different type that contains method `foobar` or if there is an `implicit class` that adds method `foobar`.

Eventually, it decides that this method is not available and thus you see the compiler error.

In case when you use `a.x`, compiler does find an implicit conversion from `A` to `B` that provides method/val `x`. Unfortunately, it does not catch the fact that this happens in the actual conversion. What compiler is doing in this case is following

```
implicit def AtoB: A => B = a => B(a.a, a.b, a.c, AtoB(a).x)
```

This does compile, but will produce StackOveflowException in runtime.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The compiler knows, that B has a x available, hence he tries to convert the a of a.x again to type B as it is an implicit method which then leads to the stack overflow. This explains everything.

Comment: @Joel this is a great example of why implicit conversions are bad and discouraged.