# Scala | How can this code be put into a macro annotation?

Tags: java, scala, spray-json

I have many wrapper classes which all they do is add type safety plus formatting. Besides the ClassName, each wrapper class is essentially the same.

```
import com.helpers.buildFormatter
import spray.json.JsonFormat

final case class ClassName(value: String)

object ClassName {
  implicit val jsonFormatter: JsonFormat[ClassName] =
    buildFormatter[ClassName]("ClassName", _.value, this.apply)
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this further? I'm wondering if an annotation, macro, or inheritance might work.

EDIT: `buildFormatter` provides custom json parsing which is why I'd like to keep it in the resulting answer

```scala
def buildStringFormatter[A](className: String, serializer: A => String, deserializer: String => A): JsonFormat[A]
```

*From comments:*
Q: Will wrapper case classes always be single-parameter, will parameter type always be `String`, will parameter name always be `value`?
A: You are correct, there would only be 1 parameter and the parameter name be `value`. I'm fine with restricting those restrictions

Comment: If this is working code and you're asking for advice on improving it, I suggest seeing if your question might be on-topic for Code Review.

Comment: This is working code but `buildFormatter` is a helper function I've left out for because it shouldn't affect any answers

Comment: the definition for `buildFormatter` is def `buildStringFormatter[A](label: String, serializer: A => String, deserializer: String => A): JsonFormat[A]`. I'll update the question

Comment: You are correct, there would only be 1 parameter and the parameter name be `value`. I'm fine with restricting those restrictions

Comment: Thank you @DmytroMitin! it looks like I should start reading into how to generate macros although those may be scary/dangerous to work with

Answer (score 3):

You can google `spray json derivation`

https://github.com/driver-oss/spray-json-derivation

https://github.com/milessabin/spray-json-shapeless

https://github.com/zackangelo/spray-json-macros

https://github.com/ExNexu/spray-json-annotation

etc.

---

Since the signature of `buildFormatter` is

```scala
def buildFormatter[T](str: String, value: T => String, apply: String => T): JsonFormat[T] = ???
```

(and you said that wrapper case classes are always single-parameter, parameter type is always `String`, parameter name is always `value`) you can try [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

```scala
import shapeless.{::, Generic, HList, HNil, Typeable}

object caseClassJsonFormats {
  implicit def caseClassJsonFormat[A <: Product, L <: HList](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, String :: HNil],
    typeable: Typeable[A]
  ): JsonFormat[A] = 
    buildFormatter[A](typeable.describe, gen.to(_).head, s => gen.from(s :: HNil))
}
```

So you define a single implicit for all case classes (instead of an implicit per each case class).

Testing:

```scala
final case class ClassName(value: String)

import caseClassJsonFormats._
implicitly[JsonFormat[ClassName]] // compiles
```

---

Alternative approach is a [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) (sbt [settings](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Macro-Projects.html) for macro projects)

```scala
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
    
@compileTimeOnly("enable macro annotations")
class jsonFormat extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro JsonFormatMacro.impl
}

object JsonFormatMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    def jsonFormatImplicit(tpname: TypeName) =
      q"""implicit val jsonFormatter: _root_.spray.json.JsonFormat[$tpname] =
            buildFormatter[$tpname](${tpname.toString}, _.value, this.apply)"""

    annottees match {
      // if there is companion object, modify it
      case (clazz@q"$_ class $tpname[..$_] $_(...$_) extends { ..$_ } with ..$_ { $_ => ..$_ }") ::
        q"$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil =>
        q"""
           $clazz

           $mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
             ..$body

             ${jsonFormatImplicit(tpname)}
           }"""

      // if there is no companion object, create it
      case (clazz@q"$_ class $tpname[..$_] $_(...$_) extends { ..$_ } with ..$_ { $_ => ..$_ }") :: Nil =>
        q"""
           $clazz

           object ${tpname.toTermName} {
             ${jsonFormatImplicit(tpname)}
           }"""
    }
  }
}
```

So you define an implicit in companion object per each case class annotated.

Testing:

```scala
@jsonFormat
final case class ClassName(value: String)

implicitly[JsonFormat[ClassName]] // compiles

  // scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-debug-lite"
//scalac: {
//  final case class ClassName extends scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val value: String = _;
//    def <init>(value: String) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  object ClassName extends scala.AnyRef {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    implicit val jsonFormatter: _root_.spray.json.JsonFormat[ClassName] = buildFormatter[ClassName]("ClassName", ((x$1) => x$1.value), this.apply)
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

Comment: Does this apply indiscriminately to case classes? Would this need to go in each class's companion object?

Comment: @irregular This works with case classes (more precisely, case classes and *case-class-like* things). What do you need besides case classes? When you defined one implicit per each case class you defined these implicits in companion objects (implicit scope). Now you define the only implicit for all case classes where you want (in some object maybe) and import it into where you need (local scope). [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html)

Comment: @irregular Sealed-trait hierarchies are also ok, just my code is for product (case-class-like) case and not coproduct (sealed-trait-like) case.

Comment: I see. I'm just imagining how production code would look. Would I have an object Foo that contains all these implicit definitions? Then import Foo._ everywhere the JsonFormat is needed? (which could be many classes that contain these wrapper classes)?

Comment: In practical terms, this definitely DRYs the code a bit. I can imagine `import caseClassJsonFormats._; implicit val jsonFormatter: JsonFormat[ClassName] = implicitly[JsonFormat[ClassName]]`
Though I do wonder if we can go even further to having the companion object extend caseClassJsonFormats maybe

Comment: @irregular I added code with macro annotation

Comment: @irregular *"Would I have an object Foo that contains all these implicit definitions?"* What all these implicit definitions? You have the only implicit `caseClassJsonFormat`. *"Then import Foo._ everywhere the JsonFormat is needed?"* You import `Foo._` (`caseClassJsonFormats._` in my notations) at the beginning of every file where you encode/decode case classes.

Comment: @irregular *"I can imagine `import caseClassJsonFormats._; implicit val jsonFormatter: JsonFormat[ClassName] = implicitly[JsonFormat[ClassName]]`"* You **either** import `caseClassJsonFormats._` (not into companion object but into where you encode/decode case classes) **or** define implicit `jsonFormatter` in every companion object per every case class. You do not do both.

Comment: @irregular I mean you can try to do both but it's not necessary. And what is important, `implicit val jsonFormatter: JsonFormat[ClassName] = implicitly[JsonFormat[ClassName]]` is wrong. Here right hand side is not `caseClassJsonFormats.caseClassJsonFormat[ClassName]`, it's actually the `jsonFormatter` that is being defined now, so you'll possibly have `null` or `NullPointerException`. If you want you can try `implicit val jsonFormatter: JsonFormat[ClassName] = { val jsonFormatter = ???;   implicitly[JsonFormat[ClassName]] }` but it's not necessary.

Comment: @irregular See details about hiding name of implicit here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917884/nullpointerexception-on-implicit-resolution

Comment: Is there a way I can debug the macro annotation? I've defined the macro but the implicit val within the companion object isn't reachable or doesn't exist.

Comment: @irregular Please read "Debugging macros" https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html#debugging-macros You should switch on `scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-debug-lite"` in `build.sbt`. Then you'll see what code is generated. Also switch on `scalacOptions += "-Xlog-implicits"` because it's about implicits. Did you set up your build for using macro annotations (`scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-annotations"` in Scala 2.13 or macro paradise in 2.10-2.12, https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html )? If you still experience issues you should probably start a new question.

Comment: @irregular Please notice that I added `@compileTimeOnly` to my answer. In this way you can check that macro annotations are actually expanded (compiler removes macro annotations after expansion, so if macro annotations are not expanded the code will not compile).

Comment: Connected discussion https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/jar3fd/how_do_people_normally_debug_macro_annotations/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option:

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

implicit val format = jsonFormat1(ClassName.apply)
```

Comment: The `buildFormatter` is a separate function i need to use which provides custom json parsing. I am more looking for an answer regarding shortening the code in the question while keeping the same functionality