# Compile error with Tagged Type and Play Json Format typeclass derivation

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, play-json

In the following example, I want to use tagged types for the ids of my classes. I've created an utility trait to reduce some boilerplate (of tags/reads/writes declaration):

```scala
import java.util.UUID
import play.api.libs.json.{Format, Json, Reads, Writes}

trait Opaque[A] {
  protected type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
  type @@[U, T] = U with Tagged[T]

  trait Tag

  def tag(a: A): A @@ Tag = a.asInstanceOf[A @@ Tag]
  def untag(a: A @@ Tag): A = a

  implicit def reads(implicit r: Reads[A]): Reads[A @@ Tag] =
    r.map(tag)

  implicit def writes(implicit w: Writes[A]): Writes[A @@ Tag] =
    w.contramap(untag)

  implicit def format(implicit r: Reads[A], w: Writes[A]): Format[A @@ Tag] =
    Format(reads(r), writes(w))
}

final case class Foo(id: Foo.FooId.T, f1: Boolean)

object Foo {
  object FooId extends Opaque[UUID] {
    type T = UUID @@ Tag
  }

  import FooId._
  implicit val fmt: Format[Foo] = Json.format[Foo]
}

final case class Bar(id: Bar.BarId.T, fooId: Foo.FooId.T, b1: String)

object Bar {
  object BarId extends Opaque[UUID] {
    type T = UUID @@ Tag
  }

  import Foo.FooId._
  import BarId._
  implicit val format: Format[Bar] = Json.format[Bar]
}
```

I have the following error from the compiler:

```scala
  implicit val format: Format[Bar] = Json.format[Bar]
                                                ^
<pastie>:43: error: No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for Opaque.<refinement>, Opaque.<refinement> in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)
```

I'm not able to explain why I'm having this behaviour, the error message is not explicit. I'm importing the `Format` for `FooId` and `BarId` needed for deriving a format for `Bar` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that names of implicits are significant.

Very simple example of that is following:

```
object MyObject {
  implicit val i: Int = ???
}

import MyObject._

implicit val i: String = ???

// implicitly[Int] // doesn't compile
// implicitly[String] // doesn't compile
```

but

```
object MyObject {
  implicit val i: Int = ???
}

import MyObject._

implicit val i1: String = ???

implicitly[Int] // compiles
implicitly[String] // compiles
```

If you want derivation `Json.format[Bar]` to work, there should be implicits `Format[Bar.BarId.T]`, `Format[Foo.FooId.T]` in scope i.e. `Format` instances for fields of `Bar`. If you make the only import

```
import Foo.FooId._
implicitly[Format[Foo.FooId.T]] // compiles
```

and

```
import BarId._
implicitly[Format[Bar.BarId.T]] // compiles
```

but if you import both, since names of implicits collide

```
import Foo.FooId._
import BarId._
// implicitly[Format[Foo.FooId.T]] // doesn't compiles
// implicitly[Format[Bar.BarId.T]] // doesn't compiles
```

For example you can move `trait Tag` outside `trait Opaque` and make the only import. Then

```
implicitly[Format[Foo.FooId.T]]
implicitly[Format[Bar.BarId.T]]
Json.format[Bar]
```

will compile.

https://youtu.be/1h8xNBykZqM?t=681 Some Mistakes We Made When Designing Implicits, Mistake #1

[NullPointerException on implicit resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917884/nullpointerexception-on-implicit-resolution)

Comment: thank you for this answer, I understand where the problem come from. I'll accept it. I've a problem understanding this part: "For example you can move trait Tag outside trait Opaque and make the only import.". Please could you elaborate ? Just to be sure, what I'm looking for is to use a different tag for each Id, by moving `Tag` outside I will have to duplicate the trait.

Comment: @stankoua Oh, I see why you wanted to have `Tag` inner.